# $xy=1$ find the minimum value of $x^{6}+x^{4}y^{2}+x^{2}y^{4}+y^{6} $

Tags: inequality, contest-math

$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and this is a math Olympiad problem.

**My Attempt :**

*Note*:$a^{2}+b^{2} \geq 2ab$ For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$x^{6}+x^{4}y^{2}+x^{2}y^{4}+y^{6} =(x^{2}+y^{2})(x^{4}+y^{4})$$
So we get:
$$(x^{2}+y^{2})(x^{4}+y^{4}) \geq 2xy(x^{4}+y^{4})$$
Since $xy=1$:
$$(x^{2}+y^{2})(x^{4}+y^{4}) \geq 2(x^{4}+y^{4})  $$
So the min of $x^{6}+x^{4}y^{2}+x^{2}y^{4}+y^{6}$ is $2(x^{4}+y^{4})$.

What can i do to get rid of this $x^{4}+y^{4} $?

Comment: $x^4+y^4\ge2x^2y^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

Replace $y$ with $\frac{1}{x}$ to find

$$f(x)=x^6+\frac{1}{x^6}+x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$=(x^3-\frac{1}{x^3})^2+2+(x-\frac{1}{x})^2+2$$

$$\ge2+2=4$$
The equality occurs if $x-1/x=0$

Alternatively if $y=x^2+1/x^2=(x-1/x)^2+2\ge2,$

$$f(x)=y^3-3y+y=y(y^2-2)\ge2(2^2-2)=?$$

Answer (score 4):

AM-GM says
$$
\frac{x^6+x^4y^2+x^2y^4+y^6}{4}\geq\sqrt[4]{x^6\cdot x^4y^2\cdot x^2y^4\cdot y^6}=1
$$
where equality is obtained iff all the four terms in the numerator are equal. And it is possible to make them equal, so we can obtain equality.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly same trick: $x^4+y^4 \ge 2x^2y^2$

You end up bounding the entire sum by $2\times 2=4$, which is achievable at $x=y=1$, so this bound is sharp.

Answer (score 0):

As $y=\frac{1}{x}$, $x^6+x^4y^2+x^2y^4+y^6=x^6+x^2=x^{-2}+x^{-6}$.

We know that, for $t\gt 0$, we have $t+\frac{1}{t}\ge 2$ with the equality satisfied if and only if $t=1$. Taking $t=x^2$ and $t=x^6$ you conclude that both $x^6+x^{-6}\ge 2$ and $x^2+x^{-2}\ge 2$, with equality satisfied if and only if $x=\pm 1$. Thus:

$$x^6+x^4y^2+x^2y^4+y^6\ge 4$$

with the equation satisfied if and only if $x=y=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with @labbattercarjee's substitution, call it $f$, and take the derivative with respect to $x$ and get:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = -\frac{6}{x^7}+6 x^5-\frac{2}{x^3}+2 x$$

Set it to $0$ to find the only real solutions are $x \pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

As $x^6 + x^4 y^2 + x^2 y^4 + y^6=(x^2+y^2)(x^4+y^4)$

$$
\frac 12(x^2+y^2)\frac 12(x^4+y^4)\ge \sqrt{x^2y^2}\sqrt{x^4y^4}=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Can't resist jumping on the bandwagon:

> Find minimum of $x^{6}+x^{4}y^{2}+x^{2}y^{4}+y^{6} $

Let $$f(x,y) = x^{6}+x^{4}y^{2}+x^{2}y^{4}+y^{6}. \tag{1}$$

Here, it is assumed that the domain of $f$ is restricted by the constraint that $(xy) = 1.$

Let $$g(x) = x^6 + x^2 + x^{(-2)} + x^{(-6)}$$

and restrict the domain of $g$ to $x > 0.$

Since $xy=1,$ the domain of $f$ is restricted to $x,y$ either both being positive or both being negative.  Also, for $(x > 0), f(x,y) = f(x,[1/x]) = g(x).$

From the definition of $g$:

$$g'(x) = 6x^5 + 2x -2x^{(-3)} - 6x^{(-7)}$$

and

$$g''(x) = 30x^4 + 2 + 6x^{(-4)} + 42x^{(-8)}.$$

At this point, there are two **immediate** conclusions:

1. $g'(x) = 0$ has a root at $x=1$.
2. $\forall $x > 0$, g''(x) > 0.$

Therefore, $g(x)$ must have a local minimum at $x=1, g(x)$ can not have a local minimum anywhere else, and the local minimum at $(x=1)$ **must** be a *global* minimum, with respect to the domain of $g$ being restricted to $(x>0)$.

Remember that the domain of $f(x,y)$ is restricted to $x,y$ either being both positive or both negative.

For $(x < 0)$, by equation (1) above, $f(x,y) = f([-x],[-y])$, so the behavior of $g(x)$ for $(x>0)$ is conclusive.